# Android / Java: GoogleApiClient won't connect

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I coded an Android Game in Java using Android Studio. Now I want to exchange the players highscore online, via the GoogleApi. So I initialize a `GoogleApiClient` in my `onCreate` function:

```
googleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(FullscreenActivity.this)
                .addApi(Games.API)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .build();
```

Where `googleApi`is a public `GoogleApiClient` variable.
Then there are:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.e("Connected?", String.valueOf(googleApi.isConnected()));
        googleApi.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.d("ConnectionFailed", String.valueOf(result));
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // !!!
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                googleApi.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if(!started){
            started = true;
            setContentView(new Game(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        if(!started){
            started = true;
            this.setContentView(new Game(this));
        }
    }
```

The output of `onConnectionFailed(...)` says: `D/ConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{2b5bddee: android.os.BinderProxy@7d0328f}, message=null}`

On my mobile the Google Play Games Login window showed up, and I logged in. Then a rotating progress circle was showing, and it disappeared. The `onConnected(...)` function never got called.
What to add/remove/edit?

*This is most likely not a duplicate, because I did not find a working solution for several other questions, that equal in content.*

Comment: Check for logs of Google Play Services https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/logging

Comment: I will look at that for first, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

During the signin process, there can be multiple calls to `onConnectionFailed`.  Have you looked at the samples in GitHub: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples ?

In the samples onConnectionFailed is implemented as:

```
 public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
        if (mIsResolving) {
            // The application is attempting to resolve this connection failure already.
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: already resolving");
            return;
        }

        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignIn) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mAutoStartSignIn = false;

            // Attempt to resolve the connection failure.
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: begin resolution.");
            mIsResolving = resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient,
                    connectionResult, RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error));
        }

        updateUI();
    }
```

And resolveConnectionFailure is:

```
public static boolean resolveConnectionFailure(Activity activity,
                                                   GoogleApiClient client, ConnectionResult result, int requestCode,
                                                   String fallbackErrorMessage) {

        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(activity, requestCode);
                return true;
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                client.connect();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // not resolvable... so show an error message
            int errorCode = result.getErrorCode();
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
                    activity, requestCode);
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                // no built-in dialog: show the fallback error message
                showAlert(activity, fallbackErrorMessage);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) This is a solution I havn't seen yet, lets see if it works :)